"Bitcoins.stackexchange.com" should redirect to "bitcoin.stackexchange.com"
I just made this typo, and I'm sure other people do too. What do you all think about adding "bitcoins.stackexchange.com" as an alias to "bitcoin.stackexchange.com"?

Seems like a good idea; not sure the SE administrators would be willing to do it. I'm unable to find precedent for it. Can anyone else think of a previous site aliasing request?
